# How to pass callback function to a JS class?

Tags: javascript

I have created a little class in JS to handle buttons across a site i'm building. When creating a new instance of a Button i want to be able to pass a callback function.

Currently i'm creating the instance like this: (Class code follows below)

```
import Button from './scripts/button';
const btn = document.getElementById('test');
new Button(btn);
```

What i want to do is something like this:

```
    import Button from './scripts/button';
    const btn = document.getElementById('test');
    new Button(btn, function() {
      console.log('im clicked');
    });
```

The code for the Button class looks like this:

```
class Button {

  constructor(el) {
    this.element = el;
  }

  /*
    more to come here, but this is to simplify stuff
  */
}

export default Button;
```

How would i do this?

Comment: Just add a second parameter to the constructor of your `Button` class, and, inside the constructor, pass this parameter to a class attribute. Essentially, do what's already being done with `el`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add the callback to the `constructor()`, and then call it within the constructor, so it looks like:

```
constructor(el, cb) {
  this.element = el;
  cb();
}
```

Comment: @mathias5 — When I told you do do that a couple of minutes ago you said you thought you were doing that already.

Comment: This will cause the callback to be invoked immediatly during the class' construction; is this what you really want?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a function to accept multiple arguments, delimit them with commas.

```
constructor(el, callback) {
```

Comment: But i want to be able to call the function when init the class, as show in my example.

Comment: You didn't say that, nor show it in your example. To call a function put `(argument, list, here)` after it: `callback()`.

Comment: I believe i did. Please see the second code snippet.

Comment: Just do what you're already doing with `this.element`. It's the same logic.

Comment: @mathias5 — The second code snippet shows you passing a callback function to your constructor function.  The third code snippet shows your constructor function ignoring it.